# Windows GPO - Mount network share for a group of computers

Tags: windows, group-policy

I want to mount a drive at logon of every users on a group of computers of my domain, there are from different OU, and they are member of a same group.

I tried to use loopback processing but the gpo remain Filtered for security.

I've read that user policies cannot apply to computer because there are not same object (it's logical).

How can I do what I want ? I looked for a wmi filter with no success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because drive maps are a “group policy preference” item, they support item level targeting. So, there are multiple ways to accomplish this.

You could easily use item-level targeting to apply the drive map based on any number of parameters, including group membership.

You should also be able to use group policy loop back processing mode. Like I mention below, both computer and user have to be able to read the policy.

However, there is a simple way to do this without item-level targeting. In order for a group policy to apply to a user, both the user and computer has to be able to read it. So, simply apply the drive map policy to the OUs and change the permissions of the policy. Allow “Domain Users” to read and apply the policy (that’s all users). Allow only the relevant computer group to read and apply. Make sure authenticated users is removed.

Now, only computers in the relevant group will be able to read the policy, preventing all users from applying the policy unless they are on a computer in that group.

Item-level targeting is really the modern way to do this. It is far more flexible.

Comment: I should have say I mount drive with a logon script with specific credentials and there is no item-lvl targeting on it . (Or i didnt found it)  But I did it without item-level targeting  like you wrote, and it works, thank you !